# Issue with Nested Form Groups, Form Array

Tags: angular

I am using a form Group. In that, I have declared a form array. Within 
    the form array, I am declaring for groups dynamically. The issue is when 
    I am updating the values in the form group, Only Inner from group values 
    and form array values are updating but outer form group values are not 
    updating.

```
this.fiscalYearForm = new FormGroup({
  fiscalYear: new FormControl(""),
  startDate: new FormControl(""),
  endDate: new FormControl(""),
  description: new FormControl(""),
  isCreateFiscalPeriod: new FormControl(false),
  noOfFiscalPeriods: new FormControl(),
  fiscalPeriods: this.fb.array([])
 });

 let control = <FormArray>this.fiscalYearForm.controls.fiscalPeriods;
 control.push(
   this.fb.group({
    periodName: ["", Validators.required],
    periodStartDate: ["", Validators.required],
    periodEndDate: ["", Validators.required],
    periodDescription: [""]
  })
 );
```

I need the values in the outer form group also. But it is not updating.

Comment: `I need the values in the outer form group also`, what do you exactly mean with this? At least I am having trouble understanding what you mean.

Comment: Your code looks all fine to me. Plus I spent 20 minutes of my time creating a form trying to replicate this issue on [StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzqca6)

You might have done something in the template probably. Take a look at the Sample stackBlitz and see what's wrong.

Comment: Update your code by adding the lines where you are updating the outer form group.

Comment: I have seen the StackBlitz Code,  <div *ngFor="let fiscalPeriod of fiscalYearForm.controls.fiscalPeriods.controls; let i = index;"
  formArrayName="fiscalPeriods"> here I have Used like this  <tbody formArrayName="fiscalPeriods">
                <tr  *ngFor="let fiscalPeriod of fiscalYearForm.get('fiscalPeriods').controls;let i = index"
                [formGroupName]="i">

Comment: I don't know exactly where the problem has occured. But I have resolved it by adding this.fiscalYearForm.updateValueAndValidity();